# Is it possible to configure IPv6 addresses for ISC DHCPv4 HA failover addresses?

Tags: configuration, isc-dhcpd

The [documentation](https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhcpdconf#configuring-failover) for ISC's `dhcpd.conf` has the example (truncated for brevity):

```
failover peer "foo" {
  primary;
  address anthrax.rc.example.com;
  port 519;
  peer address trantor.rc.example.com;
  peer port 520;
}
```

It further explains the `address` field as:

> The address statement declares the IP address or DNS name on which the server should listen for connections from its failover peer, and also the value to use for the DHCP Failover Protocol server identifier. Because this value is used as an identifier, it may not be omitted.

If I attempt to configure this as an IPv6 address similar to the following:

```
failover peer "foo" {
  ...
  address 2000:dead::beef;
  # - OR -
  address [2000:dead::beef];
  ...
}
```

The v4 daemon refuses to start:

```
Primary dhcpd[61664]: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 41: semicolon expected.
Primary dhcpd[61664]:      peer address 2000:
Primary dhcpd[61664]:                        ^
Primary dhcpd[61664]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
...
Primary dhcpd[63231]: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 41: [ (91): expecting IP address or hostname
Primary dhcpd[63231]:      peer address [
Primary dhcpd[63231]:                    ^
Primary dhcpd[63231]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
```

Is configuring v6 addresses in the v4 daemon config illegal?

Comment: From the document mentioned in the question, (https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhcpdconf#dhcp-failover), "... This version of the ISC DHCP server supports the DHCP failover protocol as documented in draft-ietf-dhc-failover-12.txt." 

In this draft, only reference to A records are made (no AAAA) while describing the relevant DNS RR relevant for the draft.

Comment: I would try replacing `address` with `address6`. Every bit of IPv6 config has a trailing `6`.

Comment: @A.B Unfortunately this also didn't work for me, even in dhcpd6.conf: `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf line 33: invalid statement in peer declaration` specifically on `address6`.